Increasing the distance between tiers in forest
I try to get more space between the penultimate line and the line at the bottom in the following type hierarchy.

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{forest}
\useforestlibrary{linguistics}
\forestapplylibrarydefaults{linguistics}

\newcommand{\type}[1]{\ifmmode\mathnormal{\mathit{#1}}\else\textnormal{\textit{#1}}\fi}


\forestset{
  % Easy extra edges
  edge to'/.style 2 args={
    tikz+={\path[#2](#1.parent anchor)--(.child anchor);}
  },
  edge to/.style={
    edge to'/.expanded={\unexpanded{#1}}{\forestoption{edge}},
  },
  edge from'/.style 2 args={
    tikz+={\path[#2](.parent anchor)--(#1.child anchor);}
  },
  edge from/.style={
    edge from'/.process=_O{#1}{#1.edge},
  },
  % Identify two (adjacent, vertically aligned) nodes.  See the explanation of
  % how this works in "type-hierarchies.tex"
  identify/.style={
    phantom,
    temptoksa/.option=#1.name,
    before typesetting nodes/.process=Rw1{temptoksa}{
      content/.option=##1.content,
      content format/.option=##1.content format,
      node format/.option=##1.node format,
    },
    for parent/.process=Ow1{n}{
      after packing node={
        for ##1={
          ignore,ignore edge,forget@node@boundary/.option=grow,
        },
      },
    },
    for nodewalk/.process=Rw1Ow1{temptoksa}{name=##1}{!u.name}{edge to={##1}},
  },
  forget@node@boundary/.code={%
    \forestolet{positive@edge@#1}\relax
    \forestolet{negative@edge@#1}\relax
  },
  % Uniformly spread any sequence of nodes
  spread/.style n args=4{
    % #1 = coordinate (x,y,s,l)
    % #2 = nodewalk to spread
    % #3 = relative node name of the node with the final coordinate
    % #4 = final coordinate shift
    for nodewalk={
      tempcounta'=-1,
      #2,
      tempdima/.pgfmath={(#1("#3")+#4-#1(""))/tempcounta()}
    }{tempcounta'+=1},
    tempdimb'=0pt,
    for nodewalk={#2}{
      #1'+/.register=tempdimb,
      tempdimb'+/.register=tempdima,
    },
  },
}

% The old type hierarchy style
\forestset{
typehierarchy/.style={for tree={parent anchor=south, child
% old version:
%    anchor=north,align=center,base=top,font=\itshape,fit=rectangle}},
% to get parallel lines:
    anchor=north,align=center,base=top,font=\itshape,calign=fixed angles}},
% if there are instances as leaves in the hiarchy
instance/.style={edge=dotted}
}

% Type hierarchy (Saso 2020)
\forestset{
  type hierarchy/.style={
    for tree={
      anchor=base,
      content format={\noexpand\type{\unexpanded{#1}\forestoption{content}}},
    },
  },
  attrib/.style={
    content format={\noexpand\attrib{\forestoption{content}}},
    draw,
  },
}

% Type hierarchy (Saso 2020)
\forestset{
  type hierarchy/.style={
    for tree={
      anchor=base,
      content format={\noexpand\type{\unexpanded{#1}\forestoption{content}}},
    },
    % The \ldots should not be in italics, so we add \normalfont to the original definition. Saso 27.05.2020
    TeX={
      \let\origldots\ldots
      \def\ldots{\normalfont\origldots}%
    },
    % Saso suggested the above rather than looking at the content, but we may use looking at the
    % content for replacing "...":
    delay={where content={...}{content=\normalfont\ldots}{}},
  },
  % Partitions are typeset in small caps (\textsc) and put in boxes (draw).
  partition/.style={
    content format={\noexpand\textsc{\forestoption{content}}},
    draw,
  },
  instance/.style={
    gray,edge={gray,dashed},align=center
  },
  % if all leaves in the hierarchy are instances, we can declare this as follows:
  % nodes which do not have children (n children=0) are drawn in gray and edges leading to them are dashed 
  instances/.style={
      for tree={
      s sep=0,
      if n children=0{
        instance   % easier to maintain if we use the style than repeat the definition of the style
      }{},
  }},
}



\begin{document}


\begin{forest}
type hierarchy, 
[finite-clause
  [internal-syntax, partition
    [root
      [v2 
        [r-wh-int, name=r-wh-int, tier=max]
        [r-decl, name=r-decl, tier=max]]
      [v1 [r-pol-int, name=r-pol-int]]]
    [subord, name=subord]]
  [clausality, partition
    [inter
      [wh, name=wh, tier=wh-polar-decl
        [s-wh-int, name=s-wh-int, tier=max]]
      [polar, name=polar, tier=wh-polar-decl
        [s-pol-int, name=s-pol-int, tier=max]]]
    [decl, name=decl, tier=wh-polar-decl
        [s-decl, name=s-decl, tier=max]]]]
\draw (wh.south) -- (r-wh-int.north);
\draw (subord.south) -- (s-wh-int.north);
\draw (subord.south) -- (s-pol-int.north);
\draw (subord.south) -- (s-decl.north);
\draw (polar.south) -- (r-pol-int.north);
\draw (decl.south) -- (r-decl.north);
\end{forest}

\end{document}

I tried several things. For example: for level=3{l*=1.5}, but this does not work since I played around with tiers.

Do you have a link(s) for the code you're using?

You can match on tier rather than level:

\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\newcommand{\type}[1]{\ifmmode\mathnormal{\mathit{#1}}\else\textnormal{\textit{#1}}\fi}

\forestset{
  % Easy extra edges
  edge to'/.style 2 args={
    tikz+={\path[#2](#1.parent anchor)--(.child anchor);}
  },
  edge to/.style={
    edge to'/.expanded={\unexpanded{#1}}{\forestoption{edge}},
  },
  edge from'/.style 2 args={
    tikz+={\path[#2](.parent anchor)--(#1.child anchor);}
  },
  edge from/.style={
    edge from'/.process=_O{#1}{#1.edge},
  },
  % Identify two (adjacent, vertically aligned) nodes.  See the explanation of
  % how this works in "type-hierarchies.tex"
  identify/.style={
    phantom,
    temptoksa/.option=#1.name,
    before typesetting nodes/.process=Rw1{temptoksa}{
      content/.option=##1.content,
      content format/.option=##1.content format,
      node format/.option=##1.node format,
    },
    for parent/.process=Ow1{n}{
      after packing node={
        for ##1={
          ignore,ignore edge,forget@node@boundary/.option=grow,
        },
      },
    },
    for nodewalk/.process=Rw1Ow1{temptoksa}{name=##1}{!u.name}{edge to={##1}},
  },
  forget@node@boundary/.code={%
    \forestolet{positive@edge@#1}\relax
    \forestolet{negative@edge@#1}\relax
  },
  % Uniformly spread any sequence of nodes
  spread/.style n args=4{
    % #1 = coordinate (x,y,s,l)
    % #2 = nodewalk to spread
    % #3 = relative node name of the node with the final coordinate
    % #4 = final coordinate shift
    for nodewalk={
      tempcounta'=-1,
      #2,
      tempdima/.pgfmath={(#1("#3")+#4-#1(""))/tempcounta()}
    }{tempcounta'+=1},
    tempdimb'=0pt,
    for nodewalk={#2}{
      #1'+/.register=tempdimb,
      tempdimb'+/.register=tempdima,
    },
  },
}

% The old type hierarchy style
\forestset{
  typehierarchy/.style={for tree={parent anchor=south, child
      % old version:
      %    anchor=north,align=center,base=top,font=\itshape,fit=rectangle}},
      % to get parallel lines:
      anchor=north,align=center,base=top,font=\itshape,calign=fixed angles}},
  % if there are instances as leaves in the hiarchy
  instance/.style={edge=dotted}
}

% Type hierarchy (Saso 2020)
\forestset{
  attrib/.style={
    content format={\noexpand\attrib{\forestoption{content}}},
    draw,
  },
% Type hierarchy (Saso 2020)
  type hierarchy/.style={
    for tree={
      anchor=base,
      content format={\noexpand\type{\unexpanded{#1}\forestoption{content}}},
    },
    % The \ldots should not be in italics, so we add \normalfont to the original definition. Saso 27.05.2020
    TeX={
      \let\origldots\ldots
      \def\ldots{\normalfont\origldots}%
    },
    % Saso suggested the above rather than looking at the content, but we may use looking at the
    % content for replacing "...":
    delay={where content={...}{content=\normalfont\ldots}{}},
  },
  % Partitions are typeset in small caps (\textsc) and put in boxes (draw).
  partition/.style={
    content format={\noexpand\textsc{\forestoption{content}}},
    draw,
  },
  instance/.style={
    gray,edge={gray,dashed},align=center
  },
  % if all leaves in the hierarchy are instances, we can declare this as follows:
  % nodes which do not have children (n children=0) are drawn in gray and edges leading to them are dashed 
  instances/.style={
      for tree={
      s sep=0,
      if n children=0{
        instance   % easier to maintain if we use the style than repeat the definition of the style
      }{},
  }},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  type hierarchy, 
  before typesetting nodes={
    where={> O_={tier}{max}}{l*=1.5}{},
  },
  [finite-clause
    [internal-syntax, partition
      [root
        [v2 
          [r-wh-int, name=r-wh-int, tier=max]
          [r-decl, name=r-decl, tier=max]]
        [v1 [r-pol-int, tier=max, name=r-pol-int]]]
      [subord, name=subord]]
    [clausality, partition
      [inter
        [wh, name=wh, tier=wh-polar-decl
          [s-wh-int, name=s-wh-int, tier=max]]
        [polar, name=polar, tier=wh-polar-decl
          [s-pol-int, name=s-pol-int, tier=max]]]
      [decl, name=decl, tier=wh-polar-decl
          [s-decl, name=s-decl, tier=max]]]]
  \draw (wh.south) -- (r-wh-int.north);
  \draw (subord.south) -- (s-wh-int.north);
  \draw (subord.south) -- (s-pol-int.north);
  \draw (subord.south) -- (s-decl.north);
  \draw (polar.south) -- (r-pol-int.north);
  \draw (decl.south) -- (r-decl.north);
\end{forest}

\end{document}

